# How to add virtual scrolling to an ant design table with custom components?

Tags: reactjs, antd, virtualscroll

I am looking for a way to add virtual scrolling to my ant design table. I found some libaries to achieve that (virtualized-table-for-antd, antd-virtualized, ...), but they seams be no longer under development and they also do not offer a possibility to use custom row Component (i overrided `components.body.row` in antd table props to add context menu to my table rows).
I also tried to use `react-window` but this breaks the table layout because it adds wrappers around the table rows.
Also the [example in the docs](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/table/demo/virtual-list.md) for virtual scrolling is very limited.

Is there a way to add virtual scrolling to my ant design table without loosing any functionallity such as using custom components for rows?

Comment: Try [Virtuallist-antd](https://github.com/crawler-django/virtuallist-antd)

Answer (score 0):

ant design provides out of the box
https://ant.design/docs/blog/virtual-table

You can pass
"<Table {...otherProps} virtual scroll= {{x: number, y: number}} pagination={false}/>"
to virtualise, this works for rows with custom component as well